# Failing to INSERT checkboxes getting undefined variable feedback

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a strange on here - so I am displaying out a list of categories from my database as checkboxes when creating a post. I tick which ones the post belong to and it should take the doc_id and also the cat_id form which box was ticked. when I turn on error reporting I get the following:

```
Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/admin/actions/new_doc.inc.php on line 53
array(4) { ["doc_name"]=> string(2) "df" ["doc_owner"]=> string(3) "dsf" ["doc_content"]=> string(3) "dsf" ["submit"]=> string(0) "" }
```

which referres to this line here:

```
$cat_ids = $_POST['cat_id'];
```

The whole block of code looks like this:

```
if (empty($errors)) { 

// MAKING THE QUERY 

$q = "INSERT INTO docs (doc_name, doc_content,  doc_owner, created_date) VALUES ('$dn', '$dc', '$do', NOW() )"; 

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); 

if ($r) { 

$doc_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc); 

$query = "INSERT INTO doc_cat_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES ";

$cat_ids = $_POST['cat_id']; 

$length = count($cat_ids); 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cat_ids); $i++) { 
$query.='(' . $cat_ids[$i] . ',' . $doc_id . ')'; 

if ($i < $length - 1) 
$query.=','; 

} 

mysqli_query($dbc, $query); 
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

And here is how I show out the checkboxes:

```
<?php

function build_cat_checkboxes(){

    global $dbc;

    $q = "SELECT * FROM cats";

    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo '<ul><li><label><input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li></ul>';
    }
}

?>
```

I cannot fathom why it is failing to insert into the doc_cat_join table where like mentioned it should be taking the doc_id and the cat_id and inserting them as a new row with an id.

Here is an example of that table view:

[image]

Comment: Watch out for [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)! You should bind your parameters.

Comment: From my example above, what is a better method of Selecting and Inserting data to and from my database table?

Comment: Use the MySQLi `preapare`, `bind` and `execute` methods. There is an example in the link I posted above.

Comment: But are you suggesting I move from mysqli_ to PDO?

Comment: No. Look for the example under the heading "MySQLi". Or look under "Prepared statements" [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli).

Comment: Thanks man, I will rewrite them for the added security!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When no checkbox has been ticked there will be no POST parameter cat_id at all.
Since that also means that the document isn't assigned to a single category this might be part of your input validation/error handling.

```
if (empty($errors)) { 
  if (!isset($_POST['cat_id'])) {
    die('no category assigned'); // or maybe a bit more sophisticated error handling
  }
```